# dns configuration for wireless access point

Tags: linux, dns, embedded-linux, iptables, access-point

I am trying to implement wireless access point on my embedded platform. I have implemented some parts like running wireless card as access point, dhcp server and some forwarding rules (via iptables). 
I have tried several iptables commands. results of all are the same. The last one I decided to use is:

```
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
echo '1' > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Access point runs successfully, clients can connect to it and get ip address. However there is DNS problem. Clients could not resolve the hostnames but they can connect via ip addresses.

DHCP configuration is as below:

```
interface wlan0
start 192.168.7.11
end 192.168.7.20
max_leases 10
option subnet 255.255.255.0
option router 192.168.7.1
#option dns 192.168.7.2 192.168.7.4
option domain local
option lease 864000
lease_file /conf/udhcpd.leases
#pidfile /tmp/udhcpd.pid
```

For this configuration, If I use 'option dns 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4' I can resolve the problem but I need to use the dns of the network. Is there any way to forward the dns address 192.168.7.2 to the dns address of the wired network (eg. 192.168.0.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find the DNS routing (eg. 192.168.7.2 to 192.168.0.2). But I have found a way to use the DNS address of the embedded platform on clients.

in DHCP server configuration, I used this option:

option dns 192.168.0.2 192.168.0.4 (conf file are generated when access point is started, so the dns addresses are obtained from the system )

after DHCP server is run, I have run these commands to forward dns addresses:

```
iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface eth1 -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface eth1 -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
```